# How to fix script error - undefined value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I wrote a Simple script which works well, but the problem is when you clear (backspace) any cell in "19Tydzień08" sheet, it takes on value "undefined". How to resolve this problem?
there is a sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_ybHZIgvQvFmAbXb2WjyuUT4QrMAakV9Z4Yt_cJWeVw/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("19Tydzień 08 (Zjazdy Kierowców)")

  var rng = e.range
  var ov = e.oldValue
  var v = e.value

  if (ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "19Tydzień08") {  
    rng.setValue(ov)

    var n = sh.getRange("C4:C").getValues().filter(String).length   
    var data = sh.getRange(4, 2, n, 7).getValues()

    // Utilities.sleep(2000)
    // SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    rng.setValue(v)
    var n = sh.getRange("C4:C").getValues().filter(String).length
    var data1 = sh.getRange(4, 2, n, 7).getValues()

    Logger.log(data)

    sh.getRange(4, 5, sh.getLastRow(), 4).clearContent();
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        if (data1[i][0] == data[j][0] && data1[i][1] == data[j][1]) {       
          sh.getRange(i+4, 5).setValue(data[j][3])
          sh.getRange(i+4, 6).setValue(data[j][4])
          sh.getRange(i+4, 7).setValue(data[j][5])
          sh.getRange(i+4, 8).setValue(data[j][6])
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a exit code/code guard. `if(!e || !v) return`

Comment: If you backspace e.value becomes undefined so just test for that.